# Log viewing utility database choice

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, hadoop, logging, nosql

I will be implementing log viewing utility soon. But I stuck with DB choice. My requirements are like below:

- Store 5 GB data daily
- Total size of 5 TB data
- Search in this log data in less than 10 sec

I know that PostgreSQL will work if I fragment tables. But will I able to get this performance written above. As I understood NoSQL is better choice for log storing, since logs are not very structured. I saw an example like below and it seems promising using hadoop-hbase-lucene:
http://blog.mgm-tp.com/2010/03/hadoop-log-management-part1/

But before deciding I wanted to ask if anybody did a choice like this before and could give me an idea. Which DBMS will fit this task best?

Comment: if i were you i will go with NoSQL

Comment: "Fragment" - do you mean partition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My logs are very structured :)

I would say you don't need database you need search engine:

- [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) based on Lucene and it packages everything what you need together
- [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) another Lucene based search engine
- [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) nice thing is that you can use multiple sources per search index -- enrich your raw logs with other events
- [Scribe](https://github.com/facebook/scribe) Facebook way to search and collect logs

Update for @JustBob:
Most of the mentioned solutions can work with flat file w/o affecting performance. All of then need inverted index which is the hardest part to build or maintain. You can update index in batch mode or on-line. Index can be stored in RDBMS, NoSQL, or custom "flat file" storage format (custom - maintained by search engine application)

Comment: +1 this is a search problem much more than it is a data storage problem. Also, there's splunk if you're willing to pay to get something OTS.

Comment: Depending on your view search and database are one in the same. Can you be more specific in what you mean you don't need a database, but a search engine?

Answer (score 4):

You can find a lot of information here:

http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis

See which fits your needs.

Anyway for such a task NoSQL is the right choice.

---

You should also consider the learning curve, MongoDB / CouchDB, even though they don't perform such as Cassandra or Hadoop, they are easier to learn.

MongoDB being used by Craigslist to store old archives: http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongodb-craigslist-one-year-later